# Media Object doesn't render images

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, reactstrap

```
    import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

```
     import React, { Component } from 'react';

    import {Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
    import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
    import './App.css';

    class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Navbar dark color="primary">
            <div className="container">
            <NavbarBrand href="/">FoodHub Restaurant</NavbarBrand>
            </div>
            </Navbar>
            <Menu />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
<------------------------------------------------------------------------------>
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Media } from 'reactstrap';

class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dishes: [
                {
                  id: 0,
                  name:'Uthappizza',
                  image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
                  category: 'mains',
                  label:'Hot',
                  price:'4.99',
                  description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.'                        },
               {
                  id: 1,
                  name:'Zucchipakoda',
                  image: 'assets/images/zucchipakoda.png',
                  category: 'appetizer',
                  label:'',
                  price:'1.99',
                  description:'Deep fried Zucchini coated with mildly spiced Chickpea flour batter accompanied with a sweet-tangy tamarind sauce'                        },
               {
                  id: 2,
                  name:'Vadonut',
                  image: 'assets/images/vadonut.png',
                  category: 'appetizer',
                  label:'New',
                  price:'1.99',
                  description:'A quintessential ConFusion experience, is it a vada or is it a donut?'                        },
               {
                  id: 3,
                  name:'ElaiCheese Cake',
                  image: 'assets/images/elaicheesecake.png',
                  category: 'dessert',
                  label:'',
                  price:'2.99',
                  description:'A delectable, semi-sweet New York Style Cheese Cake, with Graham cracker crust and spiced with Indian cardamoms'                        }
               ],
        };
    }

    render() {
        const menu = this.state.dishes.map((dish) => {
            return (
              <div key={dish.id} className="col-12 mt-5">
                <Media tag="li">
                  <Media left middle>
                      <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
                  </Media>
                  <Media body className="ml-5">
                    <Media heading>{dish.name}</Media>
                    <p>{dish.description}</p>
                  </Media>
                </Media>
              </div>
            );
        });

        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <Media list>
                  {menu}
              </Media>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Menu;
```

I'm new to react and have tried building a simple application. Also, I have used reactstrap in it. But its not displaying the images which I have put in the public/assets/images folder. Can someone please help me in this. I have tried numerous times maybe the Media object might not be compatible.Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi, did you use create-react-app to start your project?

Comment: I used npx create-react-app my-app

Comment: I gave an answer below based on getting your code to work and display some images, let me know how you get on. Rob

Comment: okkkk I would surely let you know

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the assets folder is created in the public folder and that the images folder is created in the assets folder and place the image files there.

You should see the images on the dev server then.

the full path to the images folder should be

```
PROJECT_NAME/public/assets/images
```

where PROJECT_NAME is the name you gave to create-react-app, ie. my-app

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method for display images.I hope the code is usefull

```
<img key={i} src={ require(`../../assets/${image}`) } />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. In order for the images to be rendered, you have specify the size of the image.

So instead of just:

```
<Media left middle>
      <Media object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
</Media>
```

Try this:

```
var imgStyle = {
   minWidth: "40px",
};

<Media left middle>
      <Media style={imgStyle} object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
</Media>
```